# Xamarin - binding to variable in datatemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I bind a value from my object property to a variable so that I can pass it as an argument/parameter for my method "**setFavoriteProduct(id_product, favnumber)** which is triggered by my button "choiceButton". I require the property value "id_product".

When I bind it to Label "id_productLabel" then I can see it in the View just fine but I need to use the string value in my "**setFavoriteProduct**" function.

```
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
            {   

                Image productImage = new Image();
                productImage.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "imageURL");
                //productImage.HeightRequest = 60;
                productImage.HeightRequest = 120;
                //productImage.WidthRequest = 60;
                productImage.WidthRequest = 120;
                productImage.Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit;

                Label nameLabel = new Label();
                nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "name");

                Label id_productLabel = new Label();                    
                id_productLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "id_product");
                id_productLabel.IsVisible = true;

                Button choiceButton = new Button();
                choiceButton.Text = "Vali";
                choiceButton.Clicked += (sender, args) => setFavoriteProduct(
                    id_product,
                    favnumber
                );

                return new ViewCell
                {
                    View = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(0, 5),                            
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children = { productImage, id_productLabel , nameLabel, choiceButton }
                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way to do this is to get the `BindingContext` from the sender (button) and then get the property from that

```
choiceButton.Clicked += (sender, args) => {
  var context = (MyClass)((Button)sender).BindingContext;
  var id = context.id_product;
  setFavoriteProduct(id,favnumber);
};
```

alternately, you could use the `Button`'s [Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding) and `CommandParameter` properties instead of the `Clicked` event